# Opening a URL in Android's web browser from my application?

Tags: android

Opening a URL in Android's web browser from my application?
I tried this:

```
 try {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(download_link));
        startActivity(myIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No application can handle this request."
            + " Please install a webbrowser",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: what your logcat says??

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(playStoreLink));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

you should check your link otherwise you have to show your logcate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onOpenWebBrowser(View v)
{
   Intent webPageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   webPageIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in/"));

   try {
      startActivity(webPageIntent);
   } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

   }
}
```